# Using pafy for other sites

Tags: python, download, youtube, youtube-api, pafy

Does anyone know if there's a way to manipulate the code so you can use pafy on other websites or if there's a different package that works similarly to pafy?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [youtube-dl](http://youtube-dl.org/) that will do many of the things that pafy will but on a lot more sites and download options: